# PHP Laravel App with many to many relations using Pivot Tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pivot-table

I am building a Bookmarking app with PHP's Laravel framework and would like to generate some Pivot Tables in Laravels ORM.

My Database has these tables which need relations with each other:

- Users
- Bookmarks
- Bookmark_tag_lists
- Bookmark_tags

Can someone help define what methods I would need to add to each of these Models and tables to create for the Pivot table creations and functionality described below?

---

**SQL Queries I will need to be able to get records with these calls:**

**Related to User**

- get all **bookmark_tag_lists** that belong to a **user ID**
- get all **bookmark_tags** that belong to a **user id**
- get all **bookmarks** that belong to a **user id**

**Related to bookmark_tag_lists**

- get all **bookmark_tags** that belong to a **bookmark_tag_lists id**

**Related to bookmark_tags**

- get all **bookmarks** that belong to a **bookmark_tag id**

---

**users**

- has many bookmarks
- has many bookmark_tags
- has many bookmark_tag_lists

**bookmarks**

- belong to a user
- belong to many bookmark_tags

**bookmark_tags**

- has many bookmarks
- related to an `id` column on a `users table`
- related to an `id` column on a `bookmarks table`
- related to an `id` column on a `bookmark_tag_lists table`

**bookmark_tag_lists**

- has many bookmark_tags

*

Comment: Your relationships seems to me a bit confusing. Can you please elaborate what `bookmark`, `bookmark_tag` & `bookmark_tag_lists` is for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User model:

```
public function bookmarks() {
    return $this->hasMany(Bookmark::class);
}

public function bookmarkTags() {
    return $this->hasMany(BookmarkTag::class);
}

public function bookmarkTagLists() {
    $bookmarkTags = $this->bookmarkTags;
    $bookmarkTagLists = array();
    foreach ($bookmarkTags as $bookmarkTag) {
        $bookmarkTagLists[] = $bookmarkTag->bookmarkTagList;
    }
    return array_unique($bookmarkTagLists);
}
```

Bookmark model:

```
public function user() {
    return belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function bookmarkTags() {
    return bolongsToMany(BookmarkTag::class);
}

public function tags() {
    return hasMany(BookmarkTag::class);
}
```

BookmarkTag model:

```
public function bookmarks() {
    return belongsToMany(Bookmark::class);
}

public function user() {
    return belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function bookmarkTagList() {
    return $this->belongsTo(BookmarkTagList::class);
}
```

BookmarkTagList model:

```
public function bookmarkTags() {
    return hasMany(BookmarkTag::class);
}
```